# How to use RB App Checker Lite tool in mac

Tags: macos

I  wanted to check signing details,entitlements and frame works of my apps. But i dont know how to use it.can any one share me steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open RB App Checker application and drag & drop your application in the RB App Checker window, that'll do.